# Insert the data from one table to other table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in my database

```
create table A1 (username varchar(50), Sn int);
create table A2 (username varchar(50), Sn int);
```

I am inserting the data into table A2

```
insert into A2 values("abhi",1);
insert into A2 values("abhi",2);
insert into A2 values("abhi",3);
insert into A2 values("abhi",4);
insert into A2 values("abhi",5);
insert into A2 values("abhi",,6);
```

for this I am using this query

```
insert into A1 select * from A2 where Sn >= 
(select (case when max(Sn) is null then 0 else max(Sn) end) +1 from A1) 
Limit 3;
```

Will this query work if I have 100 000 records in the table. I think while checking max it will slow down the performance . I am using event scheduler for this which will run this query automatically after every 5 minutes.

How to improve this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `A1.Sn` is properly indexed, then the subquery will be virtually instant. You can easily clock its execution time (just the subquery), or run `EXPLAIN [the subquery]` to check the execution plan.

Likewise, `A2.Sn` should obviously be indexed for the `WHERE A2.Sn >= x` condition to run quickly.

*P.S.: you subquery could be simplified as: `SELECT COALESCE(MAX(Sn), 0) +1 FROM A1`. There is no improvement possible on this query. The previous trick is just a syntactic sugar that will not impact the execution time.*